# Passing data from an HTML form via an array to $_POST

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

The following is written in ASP.NET Razor.

I have a page that dynamically creates lines in an HTML form based on results from a database query. Each row in the result set corresponds to one row in the form. Each row has two input fields that I need to be able to pass via $_POST.

```
foreach (var @row in list) {
    <li>
        <span style="width: 100px; display: inline-block">@row.Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="time[]" />minutes on
        <input type="text" name="date[]" />
    </li>
}
```

My expectation is that I would then be able to access and iterate over the data like this:

```
var timeList = Request.Form["time"];
foreach (var time in timeList) {
    // Stuff
}
```

But this isn't working. I keep getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error for timeList. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets from your names:

```
foreach (var @row in list) {
    <li>
        <span style="width: 100px; display: inline-block">@row.Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="time" />minutes on
        <input type="text" name="date" />
    </li>
}
```

The loop will create duplicate names which forms arrays in HTML, so you get what you want. However, I'm not sure if that will work when the list has a single item, so test that.

Answer (score 0):

Client HTML:

```
<form action="~/Page" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_0_id" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="product_0_name" value="Prod. #1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_1_id" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="product_1_name" value="Prod. #2" />
</form>
```

Server:

```
 string youGroupKey = "product";
 Dictionary<string, string>[] values = Request.Form
     .AllKeys
     .Where(k => k.StartsWith(youGroupKey))
     .GroupBy(k => k
         .Substring(youGroupKey.Length + 1, 1),
             (a, b) => {
                 return b
                     .ToDictionary(c => c
                         .Substring(youGroupKey.Length + 3), d => Request.Form[d]);
             }
      )
      .ToArray();
```